# How to align 'texts' to the left while inside a table (For AASTeX63)

Tags: tables, alignment, aastex

Yahallo. Fairly new to LaTeX yet getting a grasp of it. Yet, currently needing some help. So I'm running with a little bit of a 'rookie' problem while using AASTeX63 for my study. I wanted to align the texts(the '*comments*' I mean) in the table towards the left.

It should be noted that this table (deluxetable*) I'm using "hides" the third column in the \latex\ when compiled. The third column is composed of list of Nebulae c: I tried to remove the third column and it's utterly a mess ^^.

As seen in the picture, the *comments* are pretty much aligned to the right.[image]

```
\begin{deluxetable*}{cchlDlc}
\tablenum{1}
\tablecaption{Fundamental Parameters of $\alpha$ Ori. These are composed of observational best values, estimated ranges, and model-derived constraints.
\label{tab:betelgeuse}}
\tablewidth{0pt}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Property} & \colhead{Value} & \nocolhead{Common} & \colhead{References} & \colhead{Comment}
}
\startdata
T\textit{\textsubscript{eff}} & 3600 $\pm$ 25 K  & Crab Nebula & [1] & Extended to $\pm$ 200 K \\
Distance & 197 $\pm$ 45 pc & Messier 2 & [2] & Parallax adopted by Dolan et al. (2016) \\
$\Theta$disk & 42.28 $\pm$ 0.43 mas & Messier 2 & [3] & Limb-darkened \\
R\textsubscript{\(\odot\)} Upper Limit & ${\sim}$1000 R\textsubscript{\(\odot\)} & Messier 3 & [4] & Data collated from various sources \\
R\textsubscript{\(\odot\)} Lower Limit & 600 R\textsubscript{\(\odot\)} & Messier 4 & [4] & Data collated from various sources \\
M\textsubscript{\(\odot\)} Upper Limit & 19 M\textsubscript{\(\odot\)} & Messier 5 & [5] & median range; seismic analysis \\
M\textsubscript{\(\odot\)} Lower Limit & 16.5 M\textsubscript{\(\odot\)} & Butterfly Cluster & [5] & median range; seismic analysis \\
Periodicity & 388 $\pm$ 30 days & Ptolemy Cluster & [6] & Dominant; Global pulsation; Fundamental mode \\
Periodicity & 2050 $\pm$ 460 days & Lagoon Nebula & [6] & Auxiliary; Long Secondary Period - LSP \\
Age & ${\sim}$8.5 Myr & Messier 9 & [4] & Closely linked to Ori OB1a ${\sim}$10 Myr \\
log g & -0.5 & Messier 10 & [7] \\
Fe/H & 0.02 $\pm$ 0.004 & Messier 10 & [4],[8] & Proxy for Z (Metallicity); Utilized for evolutionary modelling \\
\[ m_v^{max} \] & ${\sim}$0.2 - 0.4 $\pm$ 0.02 & Messier 10 & [6],[9],[10] & Maximum $\texit{V}$-band magnitude \\
\[ m_v^{min} \] & ${\sim}$0.9 - 1.6 & Messier 10 & [6],[11] & Minimum $\texit{V}$-band magnitude; recent GDE included \\
m\textsubscript{k} & -4.00 $\pm$ 0.05 & Messier 10 & [6],[12] & $\texit{K}$-band at 2.2 microns \\
log(\textit{L}/\textit{L}\textsubscript{\(\odot\)}) & 5.10 $\pm$ 0.22 & Messier 10 & [2] & 1$\sigma$ range; Adopted by Dolan et al. (2016) \\
v sin $\texit{i}$ & 5.47 $\pm$ 0.25 km s\textsuperscript{-1} & Messier 10 & [13] & SiO emission lines; solid body rotation model \\
P\textsubscript{rot} & 31 $\pm$ 8 yrs & Messier 10 & [13] & Submillimeter range; if the inclination $\texit{i}$ = $60\degree$ \\
Inclination $\texit{i}$ & $\geqslant$ $60\degree$ & Messier 10 & [13] & Submillimeter range; If the NE hot spot is at the pole \\
V\textsubscript{rad} & 21.91 $\pm$ 0.51 km s\textsuperscript{-1} & Messier 10 & [14] \\
\enddata
\tablecomments{
1. Levesque $\&$ Massey (2020), 
2. Harper et al. (2008), 
3. Montarges et al. (2014), 
4. Dolan et al. (2016), 
5. Joyce et al. (2020), 
6. Kiss et al. (2006), 
7. Lobel $\&$ Dupree (2000), 
8. Anders $\&$ Grevesse (1989), 
9. Johnson et al. (1966), 
10. Guinan et al. (2020a), 
11. Guinan et al. (2020b), 
12. Chatys et al. (2019), 
13. Kervella et al. (2018), 
14. Famaey et al. (2008); 
GDE stands for Great Dimming Event of $\alpha$ Ori last November 2019-March 2020.}
\end{deluxetable*}
```

Thanks and I'm looking forward to everyone's help

Clear skies,

CGHA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for the [AAS journals](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/#deluxetable). The columns are over-specified, and so the compiler doesn't know what to do with the extra alignment instructions. As there are only 5 columns, including the hidden one, there should be only 5 column specifiers:

```
\begin{deluxetable*}{lchcl}
\tablenum{1}
\tablecaption{Fundamental Parameters of $\alpha$ Ori. These are composed of observational best values, estimated ranges, and model-derived constraints.
\label{tab:betelgeuse}}
\tablewidth{0pt}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Property} & \colhead{Value} & \nocolhead{Common} & \colhead{References} & \colhead{Comment}
}
\startdata
T\textit{\textsubscript{eff}} & 3600 $\pm$ 25 K  & Crab Nebula & [1] & Extended to $\pm$ 200 K \\
Distance & 197 $\pm$ 45 pc & Messier 2 & [2] & Parallax adopted by Dolan et al. (2016) \\
\enddata
\tablerefs{
1. Levesque $\&$ Massey (2020), 
2. Harper et al. (2008), 
3. Montarges et al. (2014), 
4. Dolan et al. (2016), 
5. Joyce et al. (2020), 
6. Kiss et al. (2006), 
7. Lobel $\&$ Dupree (2000), 
8. Anders $\&$ Grevesse (1989), 
9. Johnson et al. (1966), 
10. Guinan et al. (2020a), 
11. Guinan et al. (2020b), 
12. Chatys et al. (2019), 
13. Kervella et al. (2018), 
14. Famaey et al. (2008); 
GDE stands for Great Dimming Event of $\alpha$ Ori last November 2019-March 2020.}
\end{deluxetable*}
```

[image: Compiled version with truncated number of rows]